# editing CSV files in excel -sharepoint 2010 

Tags: 2010

how do i make sharepoint foundation 2010 edit CSV file in excel , as of now when i upload a csv file in sharepoint there is no icon associated with it ,so when i try to click on it 
it gives me just " save " or "cancel" option but no edit option , my client is a windows 7 box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the missing icon and the missing edit button are two different issues.

You can follow the procedures here (just substitute the Excel icon) to get the icon to display: http://www.sharepointsharon.com/2010/03/sharepoint-2010-and-adobe-pdf/

Associating the file extension with Excel may need to be done in your browser: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/3ec45ee1-65fc-4049-8fa8-cd9ebb98bd65

If that doesn't work, double-check that CVS is associated with Excel on your desktop.

Comment: should office be installed on the WFE ? for it to work

Comment: Actually, yes, you should do that anyway for the search IFilters.